# Dúvida sobre soma de informações

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo uns exercícios sobre variáveis compostas e cheguei a um impasse no meu código, que a princípio não consigo resolver apesar de parecer ser algo simples.

Na hora da exibição do resultado, as notas dos alunos não estão sendo exibidas individualmente, e sim a soma de todas, ou seja: o Aluno 1 exibe as notas corretamente, o Aluno 2 exibe as notas do 1 além das próprias, e o 3 exibe as anteriores e a dele.

Preciso saber como faço pra mostrar todas as notas de cada aluno individualmente, sem mostrar as dos anteriores.

Imagino que o problema esteja na forma que eu defini a variável "registromostrar2"

Segue o código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class exercicio3{

    static final int NOTAS = 6;

    static class ALUNO {
        String Nome, Curso;
        int Semestre, Sala;
        double Notas [] = new double [NOTAS];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int alunos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a quantidade de alunos que irá registrar."));
        ALUNO Alunos [] = new ALUNO [alunos];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < alunos; i++){
            int numaluno = i+1;
            Alunos[i] = new ALUNO ();
            Alunos[i].Nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o nome do aluno " + numaluno + ":");
            Alunos[i].Curso = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o curso do aluno " + numaluno + ":");
            Alunos[i].Semestre = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o semestre(1 ou 2) do aluno " + numaluno + ":"));
            Alunos[i].Sala = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a Sala do aluno " + numaluno + ":"));

            for(j = 0; j < NOTAS; j++){
                int qualnota = j+1;
                Alunos[i].Notas[j] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a " + qualnota + " nota do aluno " + numaluno + ":"));
            }

        }


        String registromostrar1 = "";
        String registromostrar2 = "";
        String registromostrar3 = "";

        for(i = 0; i < alunos; i++){
            int numaluno = i+1;
            for(j = 0; j < NOTAS; j++){
                registromostrar2 +=  Alunos[i].Notas[j] + " ; ";
            }

            registromostrar1 = "Dados do aluno " + numaluno + ":" + "\nNome: " + Alunos[i].Nome + "." +
            "\nCurso: " + Alunos[i].Curso + "." +
            "\nSemestre: " + Alunos[i].Semestre + "." +
            "\nSala: " + Alunos[i].Sala + "." +
            "\nNotas: " + registromostrar2;

            registromostrar3 += registromostrar1 + "\n\n\n";

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, registromostrar3);





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é simples, você esqueceu de zerar sua varável **registromostrar2**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static final int NOTAS = 6;

    static class ALUNO {
        String Nome, Curso;
        int Semestre, Sala;
        double Notas [] = new double [NOTAS];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int alunos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a quantidade de alunos que irá registrar."));
        ALUNO Alunos [] = new ALUNO [alunos];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < alunos; i++){
            int numaluno = i+1;
            Alunos[i] = new ALUNO ();
            Alunos[i].Nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o nome do aluno " + numaluno + ":");
            Alunos[i].Curso = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o curso do aluno " + numaluno + ":");
            Alunos[i].Semestre = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o semestre(1 ou 2) do aluno " + numaluno + ":"));
            Alunos[i].Sala = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a Sala do aluno " + numaluno + ":"));

            for(j = 0; j < NOTAS; j++){
                int qualnota = j+1;
                Alunos[i].Notas[j] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a " + qualnota + " nota do aluno " + numaluno + ":"));
            }

        }


        String registromostrar1 = "";
        String registromostrar2 = "";
        String registromostrar3 = "";

        for(i = 0; i < alunos; i++){
            int numaluno = i+1;
            registromostrar2 ="";
            for(j = 0; j < NOTAS; j++){

                registromostrar2 +=  Alunos[i].Notas[j] + " ; ";
            }

            registromostrar1 = "Dados do aluno " + numaluno + ":" + "\nNome: " + Alunos[i].Nome + "." +
            "\nCurso: " + Alunos[i].Curso + "." +
            "\nSemestre: " + Alunos[i].Semestre + "." +
            "\nSala: " + Alunos[i].Sala + "." +
            "\nNotas: " + registromostrar2;

            registromostrar3 += registromostrar1 + "\n\n\n";

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, registromostrar3);
    }

}
```

Segue destacado a parte do código que você precisa zerar para que não ocorra o "acumulo" indevido do outro aluno :

```
 for(i = 0; i < alunos; i++){
        int numaluno = i+1;
    //Linha adicionada
    registromostrar2 ="";
        for(j = 0; j < NOTAS; j++){

            registromostrar2 +=  Alunos[i].Notas[j] + " ; ";
        }

        registromostrar1 = "Dados do aluno " + numaluno + ":" + "\nNome: " + Alunos[i].Nome + "." +
        "\nCurso: " + Alunos[i].Curso + "." +
        "\nSemestre: " + Alunos[i].Semestre + "." +
        "\nSala: " + Alunos[i].Sala + "." +
        "\nNotas: " + registromostrar2;

        registromostrar3 += registromostrar1 + "\n\n\n";

    }
```

Comment: Não esqueça de classificar a resposta positivamente, caso tenha lhe ajudado!

Comment: Valeu, não acredito que era isso hahaha! obrigado :3